# Import address text file

Tags: r, import, read.csv

I have a text file with a few million lines. Each row should have 10 variables. It is comma separated, but every once in a while there is a comma in the middle of a variable (example: row 3, "BLDG #5,#104" should be one variable, but when I import using `read.csv()` it mucks everything up). Here is an example:

```
1,09/29/1951,F,N,22 MAIN STREET AVE,APT 3,SEATTLE,WA,98102-3053,00920670025
2,09/28/1950,F,N,13354 A STREET,APT 2,BURLINGTON,VT,10101,02510070025
3,10/18/1949,M,N,600 CENTRE STREET,BLDG #5,#104,SPRINGFIELD,IL,01010,02141650025 
4,10/18/1955,M,N,5 KELLY AVENUE,,CITY,XI,10101,02141650025
```

Any recommendations on how to best import this data?

Comment: if it is a text file why are you using `read.csv()` if you want to read large files fast, try using `fread(FILE, sep=",")` from `library(data.table)` ... if it is a .csv file then try using `read.csv2()` @afleishman

Comment: The otehr ting that is mucking with your input is that "#". It the "comment.char" by default. If the extraneous commas are always surrounded by octothorpes, there might be a solution. I know how to identify lines that have excess numbers of commas. Why don't you do a bit more detective work and describe the problem more completely?

Comment: I don't get the vote to close, particularly the reason why.  Maybe someone accidentally hit vote to close?

Comment: @TylerRinker This is the third question tonight in the [r] tag where there's been a "bad actor" using that close reason on valid questions. I flagged it to the uber SO mods to see if they can do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use what `read.csv` does to your advantage?

```
dat <- read.csv(text="1,09/29/1951,F,N,22 MAIN STREET AVE,APT 3,SEATTLE,WA,98102-3053,00920670025
2,09/28/1950,F,N,13354 A STREET,APT 2,BURLINGTON,VT,10101,02510070025
3,10/18/1949,M,N,600 CENTRE STREET,BLDG #5,#104,SPRINGFIELD,IL,01010,02141650025 
4,10/18/1955,M,N,5 KELLY AVENUE,,CITY,XI,10101,02141650025", 
           header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, comment.char="", fill=TRUE)

for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  if (is.na(dat[i, "V11"])) {
    dat[i, 8:11] <- dat[i, 7:10]
    dat[i, "V7"] <- NA
  }
}

dat

##   V1         V2 V3 V4                 V5      V6   V7          V8 V9        V10        V11
## 1  1 09/29/1951  F  N 22 MAIN STREET AVE   APT 3 <NA>     SEATTLE WA 98102-3053  920670025
## 2  2 09/28/1950  F  N     13354 A STREET   APT 2 <NA>  BURLINGTON VT      10101 2510070025
## 3  3 10/18/1949  M  N  600 CENTRE STREET BLDG #5 #104 SPRINGFIELD IL       1010 2141650025
## 4  4 10/18/1955  M  N     5 KELLY AVENUE         <NA>        CITY XI      10101 2141650025
```

If you want to combine `V6` + `V7` then that's totally doable.

Doing this with a `data.table` flair would be far more efficient (i.e. if someone posts an `fread` + pure `data.table` solution that shld get the "answer" tick.

Answer (score 1):

This identifies the lines with extra fields using countfields, and then uses `sub` to remove the commas between two octothorpes ("#"). Given the size of the dataset, I'm guessing there will be more problems and you should find that `count.fields` will be very useful (see below):

```
> Lines
[1] "1,09/29/1951,F,N,22 MAIN STREET AVE,APT 3,SEATTLE,WA,98102-3053,00920670025\n2,09/28/1950,F,N,13354 A STREET,APT 2,BURLINGTON,VT,10101,02510070025\n3,10/18/1949,M,N,600 CENTRE STREET,BLDG #5,#104,SPRINGFIELD,IL,01010,02141650025\n4,10/18/1955,M,N,5 KELLY AVENUE,,CITY,XI,10101,02141650025"
> myLines <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
> myLines
[1] "1,09/29/1951,F,N,22 MAIN STREET AVE,APT 3,SEATTLE,WA,98102-3053,00920670025"     
[2] "2,09/28/1950,F,N,13354 A STREET,APT 2,BURLINGTON,VT,10101,02510070025"           
[3] "3,10/18/1949,M,N,600 CENTRE STREET,BLDG #5,#104,SPRINGFIELD,IL,01010,02141650025"
[4] "4,10/18/1955,M,N,5 KELLY AVENUE,,CITY,XI,10101,02141650025"                      
> myLines[ count.fields(textConnection(myLines),sep=",", comment.char="") >10] <- sub("(#\\d+)(\\,)#", "\\1 &", myLines[ count.fields(textConnection(myLines),sep=",", comment.char="") >10])
> myLines
[1] "1,09/29/1951,F,N,22 MAIN STREET AVE,APT 3,SEATTLE,WA,98102-3053,00920670025"     
[2] "2,09/28/1950,F,N,13354 A STREET,APT 2,BURLINGTON,VT,10101,02510070025"           
[3] "3,10/18/1949,M,N,600 CENTRE STREET,BLDG #5 &104,SPRINGFIELD,IL,01010,02141650025"
[4] "4,10/18/1955,M,N,5 KELLY AVENUE,,CITY,XI,10101,02141650025"                      
> read.csv(text=myLines, comment.char="",header=FALSE)
  V1         V2 V3 V4                 V5           V6          V7 V8         V9        V10
1  1 09/29/1951  F  N 22 MAIN STREET AVE        APT 3     SEATTLE WA 98102-3053  920670025
2  2 09/28/1950  F  N     13354 A STREET        APT 2  BURLINGTON VT      10101 2510070025
3  3 10/18/1949  M  N  600 CENTRE STREET BLDG #5 &104 SPRINGFIELD IL      01010 2141650025
4  4 10/18/1955  M  N     5 KELLY AVENUE                     CITY XI      10101 2141650025
```

I suggest using `table(count.fields( filename, sep=",", comment.char="")))` to get a better estimate of the magnitude of the problem. I suspect you just found the first of many.